# Extending Intellisense on specific language constructs (namely Attribute constructors)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, attributes, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I've written a custom attribute for decorating methods.  The attributes help add non-critical but very helpful contextual data to the method.  Currently, this helps with debugging, but eventually it will help with static analysis.

Because the Master of the data specified in the attributes is on a server and queriable, I figured I'd write a Visual Studio Intellisense extention to help my developers.  The extension would kick in when typing in parameters in my Attribute's constructor.  The completion suggestions would essentially be query results.

I've read and implemented a [Statement Completion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx) example on MSDN with relative success.

The example is for Completion on PlainText.  I've changed it to work on Code instead.  I'm one step closer.  The problem I'm having, however, is that I can't seem to find how to make it aware of its context.  The Completion kicks an whenever I type *any* code.  I'd like it to be a bit more discriminating than this.

**Question:**  Is it possible to make a custom Visual Studio Statement Completion extension aware of the language constructs around it?

I'd like to be able to only trigger Statement Completion when I'm typing into an Attribute's constructor.  And, if possible, preferably only on Attributes derived from a given base class.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: Well, yes and no. The built-in VS C# code analyzer [may be available](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d4811bc-f374-4dd5-8b11-c6516742c616/parsing-c-method-calls-in-an-extension?forum=vsx), but it's probably not very easy to make use of. You can certainly get the syntax highlighting tagger, at the very least (via either the `IClassifierAggregatorService` or `IBufferTagAggregatorFactoryService`, depending on if it's implemented as an `IClassifier` or `ITagger`), and try to do a rough parse on the line yourself.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of looking into how the syntax highlighting worked to see if it would grant me access to finer parsing details, but that seemed hackish.  I'll take a look at the first link you sent.  It seems to reference the same undocumented API some of the MSDN examples refer to.  Should be fun :)

Answer (score 1):

No. This is why we're building Roslyn, but until then you might be able to use a third-party parser, or your own hacked up parser or heuristics to make it work.

Comment: I suspected Roslyn would be the easiest way to do this.  I can't wait for it to come out!  Thanks!